# Why did the array lose the last element when passed into another function?

Tags: arrays, c

I made an static int arr[3] and set to 1, 2, 3.

I can print 1, 2, 3 in the same function.

But when I pass the array it only prints 1, 2.

Why? What happened? How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int* arr){
size_t n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
  }
}

int* makearray()
{
        static int arr[3];
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = 2;
        arr[2] = 3;

        printf("The Array before passing onto stack\n");
        size_t n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ printf("%d\n",arr[i]);}

        printf("\nThe Array when attempting to pass to another function\n");
        printArray(arr);
        return arr;
}
int main(void) {

  int* m = makearray();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a common beginner's mistake.  C doesn't automatically pass the size of an array along with its address.  It just passes a pointer to the array.  Look at the declaration of `arr` in `printArray`.  It's a pointer, right?  So `sizeof(arr)` will be the size of a pointer, not the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

By converting your array to a pointer, you removed the information that `sizeof` needs to know its total length.

Instead, it just gives you the size of a single `int *`, which is twice the size of a single `int` on your machine.

Hence, you only see the first two elements.

In C, you're basically forced to pass around the length alongside the pointer. You can wrap the two in a struct to make it easier to use, but don't expect the niceties of other languages you may be used to.